# Unable to find wso2am-2.1.0 swagger-UI source code

Tags: wso2-api-manager, swagger-ui

We are using wso2am-2.1.0. and we would like to customize the layout for the swagger UI within SW.  Please share the git repo for WS02 2.1.0 source code  that will have  swagger UI related file such as swagger-ui-bundle.js, swagger-ui.css, swagger-ui.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSO2 API Manager 2.1.0 related features resides in carbon-apimgt repo [1]. Respective carbon-apimgt version is 6.1.66. You can find the store feature which contains the Swagger integration in [2].

[1] - https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/tree/v6.1.66

[2] -  https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/tree/v6.1.66/features/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.store.feature/src/main/resources/store/site/themes/wso2/templates/api/swagger/swagger